# OpenCV extended image processing - filters

Tags: c++, opencv

How do I access the OpenCV extended image process module? I need one filter specifically: **fastGlobalSmootherFilter**.

I have OpenCV 3.2.0 incorporated into my C++ project. I'm looking for this method:
http://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d17/group__ximgproc__filters.html#gaf8673fe9147160ad96ac6053fac3c106

which is in this module:
http://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d2d/group__ximgproc.html.

I found it through the research page here:
https://sites.google.com/site/globalsmoothing/

I've tried searching through the OpenCV header files, but none reference this function. I can't find `edge_filter.hpp` which is supposed to house some of these filters. How does one actually call the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At OpenCV developer site, you will find instructions for building the contrib modules (or extras)

https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/README.md

By default, they are not included in your build.

Comment: Ah ha! The "extra modules" are not included in the build by default. I wish this had been clearer in the documentation.